# what does "you have broken package." mean?

Tags: g++

when I try to install g++  by 
"sudo apt-get install g++"
command line gives me the msg "Unable to install....You have broken packages."
How can I fix it??? And what does that "broken package" mean??? plz help....

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem.
To fix it in the major part of the cases, from your Terminal (or xTerm, or VT) execute in order:

1. `sudo apt-get clean`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get -f install`
4. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

You will need a stable internet connection and the repositories enabled.

Please, feel free to comment under here if you have other inherent questions,
have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

It's means you have not installed all dependencies of a package.
You can install them by `sudo apt-get install -f`

Answer (score 0):

Try: sudo apt-get install -f -y

That should typically fix any missing dependencies (the usual cause for a broken package).